# mod_proxy Getting 200 OK response instead of 206/406

Tags: apache2, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

Instead of getting the file in chunks, after the first chunk is finished downloaded I'm getting 200 response instead of 206/406, and the download is finished with a partial file.

what can cause that? garbage in cache?

file size: 90MB
Apache version: 2.2.24